# Java list of waiting threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a way to get a list of waiting threads/number of waiting threads on an object?

Comment: For programmatic purposes or for finding out how to solve a liveness problem?

Comment: @Bozho I want to synchronize threads which have same parameters only. I did this by having a params <-> object map. So any thread checks this and calls object.wait() if other thread is running (Object will hold a variable to tell this), the original thread will call notify() always, so one of the waiting threads resume.

Comment: @Bozho The problem was the param<-> object map was accumulating values. So the entries had to be removed after notify, only when no threads are waiting on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using the `synchronized` keyword - no. But if you are using the `java.util.concurrent` locks, you can.

`ReentrantLock` has a protected method `getWaitingThreads()`. If you extend it, you can make it public.

Update: You are using `.wait()` and `.notify()`, so you can manually fill and empty a `List<Thread>` - before wach `.wait()` call `list.add(Thread.currentThread()`, and remove it before each notify. It's not perfect, but actually you shouldn't need such a list.

Comment: I'm using only wait() and notify() as I need to synchronize only specific threads based on the values they're carrying.

Comment: well, when you call `wait()` you can add the thread manually to a list. And then, when calling notify - to remove it

Answer (score 9):

You can use the JMX classes to inspect the threads:

```
ThreadInfo[] infos = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().dumpAllThreads(true, true);
```

Each blocked thread has a non null `LockInfo` associated that will let you identify on what object it's waiting:

```
for (ThreadInfo info : infos) {
    LockInfo lockInfo = info.getLockInfo();
    if (lockInfo != null 
            && lockInfo.getClassName().equals(lock.getClass().getName()) 
            && lockInfo.getIdentityHashCode() == System.identityHashCode(lock)) {

        System.out.println("Thread waiting on " + lock + " : " + info.getThreadName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on JDk 1.6 then `ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()` is the best way to find out about all the threads waiting on object
For JDK before 1.6 you can use thread group to find out all the threads and then inspect thread stack to find out about object on which they are waiting.