# How to terminate waiting threads created by interrupting third party thread

Tags: java, multithreading, text-to-speech, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I believe I have researched answers to similar problems and have not found the answer to my specific issue.

I am using an open source Text-To-Speech software from a third party in Java, and when I cancel and/or interrupt the text to speech message, child threads of the TTS thread are left in a waiting state. Using JConsole, I find messages for each waiting thread like:

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.put(Unknown Source)

Is there a way I can interrupt or cancel a thread while safely cascading the stoppage of all other child threads?

I have experimented with an ExecutorService, daemon threads, and synchronous logic.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a reference to that thread, you can `interrupt()` it directly. That doesn't necessarily mean it will actually stop what it's doing, though. The person who wrote it could ignore any interrupted state, thrown `InterruptedException`s, etc.

Comment: It's a bug in the Text-To-Speech software from a third party. They should release threads as they don't need them. Report a bug. Look for the close or destroy methods. Maybe there are some closure methods that are not called properly.

Comment: You can get a list of waiting threads as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929351/java-list-of-waiting-threads).