# Get python threads waiting on lock

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

For all active threads waiting on any lock, how can you determine which threads are waiting for which locks?

Comment: There's no published interface for determining who's waiting for a lock (or even who owns it currently). This sort of sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe if you explain what you're trying to accomplish, there's another way to do it.

Comment: The goal is to determine what tools can be used to debug multithreading lock contention/thread starvation issues in Linux/Python. Java exposes this somewhat (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12470066). But given threading is traditionally such a hard thing to debug I'd hoped that people had either come up with tricks to aid in debugging or that sota runtimes might help expose this information natively to avoid everyone resorting to one-off tricks.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. You'd probably have to implement something yourself, like a context manager to use in `with lock` that can keep track of which objects are waiting for the lock, so you can query it. It's possible such a thing already exists somewhere.